# could not connect to server: No such file or directory in PostgreSQL

Tags: 14.04, postgresql, debian

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab127.2 x86_64) and also have Postgresql installed. I'm using Postgresql in a ruby on rails application. Suddenly my application stopped working throwing the error

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server
>   running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

```
    $psql -V 
     psql (PostgreSQL) 11.0 (Ubuntu 11.0-1.pgdg14.04+2)

    $pg_config --version
      PostgreSQL 11.0 (Ubuntu 11.0-1.pgdg14.04+2)

    $postgres -V
     The program 'postgres' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
     apt-get install postgres-xc

   $locate bin/postgres
    /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres

  $/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres -V
    postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.0 (Ubuntu 11.0-1.pgdg14.04+2)

  $pg_lsclusters
  9.3 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
  11  main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

The postgres status is down

```
 $service postgresql status
 9.3/main (port 5432): down
 11/main (port 5433): down

 $systemctl status postgresql.service

  postgresql.service
  Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
 Active: inactive (dead)

 $systemctl status postgresql@9.3-main.service

   postgresql@9.3-main.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

> $grep -H '^port' /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
>           /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf:port = 5433
>           /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf:port = 5432

I am trying to start Postgresql 9.3  with

```
 $service postgresql start 9.3
    * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                          
    * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.3-main.service failed 
     to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl 
     status postgresql@9.3-main.service' for details.


  $sudo systemctl start postgresql
   Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql.service failed to load: No 
   such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status 
    postgresql.service' for details.


   $/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
    * Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server                                                                                           
    * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@11-main.service failed to 
    load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status 
    postgresql@11-main.service' for details.

    [fail]
   * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                          
   * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.3-main.service failed to 
    load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status 
    postgresql@9.3-main.service' for details.
    [fail]
```

I'm unable to start PostgreSQL.I don't understand why it went down suddenly, it was working fine till yesterday.

Comment: It might be due do systemd "generators" not working. I'm sure I have seen this in 14.04. Bits of answers to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/830346/ might help

Comment: In the meantime `pg_ctlcluster` with the right arguments for each instance will probably start them up without problem, until the next reboot.

Comment: @DanielVérité, Thank you for the quick response.i'm a noob in Ubuntu and PostgreSQL, so can you please help me out in restarting the Postgresql. Kindly elaborate your answer. I want to have PostgreSQL up and running as earlier without losing the data.

Comment: @DanielVérité, can you please help me out to fixing the " systemd generators not working "problem? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @DanielVérité, "pg_ctlcluster with the right arguments for each instance will probably start them up without problem".How to do that ?.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `pg_lsclusters`, your PostgreSQL instances `9.3/main` and `11/main` are not started. That explains the "could not connect to server" error.

`postgresql.service` and `postgresql@9.3-main.service` are `systemd` unit files and your problem seems to be that they're missing when `systemctl` needs them.
Note that `systemctl` does not get installed by default on Ubuntu 14.04, as it's the last version that doesn't use systemd (see [Is Ubuntu 14.04 using systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490946/is-ubuntu-14-04-using-systemd)) . But somehow `systemd` got installed on your system.

With systemd, normally the postgres service files should be automatically created by `/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator`, provided by the `postgresql-common` package, and end up as `*.service` unit files in `/lib/systemd/system/`.

I cannot guess why that part didn't work or ceased to work on your system.

### How to start PostgreSQL manually

The `pg_ctlcluster` command works independently of systemd or upstart.
You should be able to start the PostgreSQL instances with:

```
$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main start
$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main start
```

Comment: In my case postgresql.conf file's ownership was changed. "sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main start" helped me to idenify this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `systemd` was running on Ubuntu 14.04 but this is supported earliest from 16.04. So I ran
sudo apt-get remove systemdIn my case `systemd` was running on Ubuntu 14.04 but this is supported earliest from 16.04. So I ran

```
sudo apt-get remove systemd
```

After, postgresql service has been run with success.