# Can't start postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, database

Hi from one day to another day postgresql didn't start :(.

When I type: psql then this error appears:

could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I also changed: listen addresses="*".

When I type: pg_lscluster

9.6 main    5432 down    /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log

The status is down and I can't start it.

Then I checked the log file:

/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key« allows access from group or world.

and there are also some other errors.

I also tried to reinstall it but it didn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089196/488351)?

Comment: yes, it didn't work. but thx